# qgis2web Polygon Layer Overwhelming Popup Selection of Point Layer

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I have a map of a point shapefile layer over a poylgon shapefile layer of legislative districts. When I export with qgis2web, the popup will only show the fields from the polygon layer. Here are examples of what happens with OL3:

[image: When polygon is not in use]

[image: WHen Polygon is in use]

With Leaflet, I have to change the polygon background to transparent or it covers over the dot layer. The issue is still the same with the popups not ever displaying the point layer information when the polygon layer is engaged.

Is there anything I can do to allow for the point layer to be clicked to a popup in this situation?

If it is relevant I am using Windows 10, QGIS 2.12.3 and qgis2web 1.19.0

Comment: Do you want popups for both layers? IIRC you can enable popups for each layer in qgis2web options. I think your question is more about how to modify the `Leaflet.js` code to do what you want than `qgis2web` options.

Comment: You mean you want to disable popups for the polygon layer?